# Do you know of a free .Net component for visual flow model graph design and editing?

Tags: c#, graph, modeling

An app (C#4, WinForms, Entity Framework, SQL Server 2008) of mine maintains a graph of interconnected objects, each having some simple member fields and a set of many directed (in and out) one-to-one links to other objects.

I'd like to offer a user an ability to view and edit this graph visually some way, creating and removing connections, modifying objects attributes values and introducing/dropping objects.

I suppose there has to be a framework (at list a primitive kind of) for this as visual model design tools are pretty common to meet. Do you know one?

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago I collaborated with [a project](http://www.ucse.edu.ar/fma/sepa/) that used this kind of tool to build parsing software for education. The tool that was used was [Graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/), in special dot and dotty. If you don't know what is it, then this is a short description about it:

> Graphviz is open source graph
>   visualization software. It has several
>   main graph layout programs.
>
> The Graphviz layout programs take
>   descriptions of graphs in a simple
>   text language, and make diagrams in
>   several useful formats such as images
>   and SVG for web pages, Postscript for
>   inclusion in PDF or other documents;
>   or display in an interactive graph
>   browser. (Graphviz also supports GXL,
>   an XML dialect.)
>
> Graphviz has many useful features for
>   concrete diagrams, such as options for
>   colors, fonts, tabular node layouts,
>   line styles, hyperlinks, and custom
>   shapes.

This is an example of the kind of graphs that were built:

[image]
<sub>(source: [ucse.edu.ar](http://www.ucse.edu.ar/fma/sepa/images/earley_un_clasico.png))</sub>

You should note that this is not a native .NET tool, but of course, you can use it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might come a little late, but Microsoft has its own .Net library called [Microsoft Automated Graph Layout](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/msagl/) (MSAGL) which looks (at least visually) suspiciously similar to GraphViz, or, DOT in particular. Its name has changed over time as it has been developed in MS Labs/MS Research.

[image]

According to the product page, it contains three modules:

1. Graphing module `Microsoft.MSAGL.dll`,
2. Drawing module `Microsoft.MSAGL.Drawing.dll`, and
3. Viewer control `Microsoft.MSAGL.GraphViewerGDIGraph.dll` that seems to be a Windows Forms custom control.

This software used to be free a long time ago, but, unfortunately, it has made it into a paid product.